# confused about the concept of timesteps and output shape in keras.layers.RNN

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

> keras.layers.RNN
>
> Input shape
>   3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim).
>
> Output shape
>
> if return_state: a list of tensors. The first tensor is the output. The remaining tensors are the last states, each with shape  (batch_size, units).
>
> if return_sequences: 3D tensor with shape  (batch_size, timesteps, units).
>   else, 2D tensor with shape (batch_size, units).

1.I am comfused about the concept of timesteps.

2.I am confused about the process that how  it deals with the input of three axes.

## Simplified code

```
import keras
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.engine import Layer
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import preprocess_input
from keras.layers import Conv2D, UpSampling2D, InputLayer, Conv2DTranspose, Input, Reshape, merge, concatenate
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard 
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers.core import RepeatVector, Permute
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from skimage.color import rgb2lab, lab2rgb, rgb2gray, gray2rgb
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.io import imsave
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers.recurrent import GRU
from keras.layers.merge import add

encoder_input = Input(shape=(32, 32, 1))

rnn_size = 16
encoder_output = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_input)
sequence_output = Reshape(target_shape=(32, 512))(encoder_output)  
gru_1 = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=False,kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1')(sequence_output)
gru_1b = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1_b')(sequence_output)
gru1_merged = add([gru_1, gru_1b])
gru_2 = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True,kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2')(gru1_merged)
gru_2b = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2_b')(gru1_merged)
sequence_output = concatenate([gru_2, gru_2b])
sequence_output = K.expand_dims(sequence_output, 3)
fusion_output = concatenate([encoder_output,sequence_output ], axis=3) 

model = Model(inputs=encoder_input, outputs=fusion_output)
model.summary()
```

## output error

> ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 32, 32, 16), (None, None, 32, 1)]

I thought the shape of 'sequence_output' would be (None, 32, 32, 1).But it was (None, None, 32, 1).I didn't know what went wrong so I started to doubt my understanding about RNN.

## What I have done

## 1.output gru1 and gru_1b

after annotation:

'#sequence_output = K.expand_dims(sequence_output, 3)'

'#fusion_output = concatenate([encoder_output,sequence_output ], axis=3)'
Then I got ()[image: output]

#### I am quite confused about the shape of gru1 and gru_1b. Why they are different?

## 2.I set return_sequences and return_state True and then got

valueerror:
[image]
In fact I have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more suitable for Cross Validated forum but ok.

So to answer your first question, timesteps is just a number that denotes the length of a sequence. RNNs work in a specific manner because they have a recurrent connection back to itself. Very good explanation of RNNs is given [here](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) on the example of LSTM. There you can see the difference between `cell state` and `state`.

To answer the second question, `(batch_size, timesteps, units)` is a output dimension. `timesteps` is again, dimensionality of the input sequence and it's something you should standardize and define on input shape (all sequences on the input have to be of the same length, if they're not, you should pad them to a specified length). `units` is a dimensionality of the output, it's output of every RNN cell you have in your layer.

The whole point of those `return_state` and `return_sequences` arguments is what you need for the next layer and for your computations. The first one is there to return cell state as the first element of the output. The second one is the states after every timestep. So after every word (or sequence element) is read, RNN updates the `state` based on the read input element and `cell state`. So, with `return_sequences` you can get sequence after every word is processed inside the RNN and the `state` has been updated.

I think that everything will be much clearer after you read that blog post I linked in this answer. I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I have read the post you linked.But I still struggle.I simplify the code which displays the reason why I put up this question.

Comment: Try printing the shape of `gru_1` and `gru_1b`. Try to understand why are the shapes like that. Also try creating layers with all combinations of `return_sequences` and `return_state` and see what are the output shapes. I think that this will clear the situation for you. If you still struggle to understand, paste the output shapes of each created layer in your question and I'll try to explain it to you in detail. But I believe it will be better if you try to figure it out alone.

Comment: Thanks for your spending time on my question. I have tried to print gru_1 and set return_stare=True.I have pasted what I have done.

Comment: No problem. OK, now see how `gru_1b` has one shape more. It's because `gru_1b` has a `return_sequences` set to `True`. Your input is of length 32. It means, after each part of the input (each timestep), `gru_1b` generates a sequence and stores it in a return tensor. Hence one extra dimension of the output. Now with that said, I hope it's clearer how to work with RNN in Keras. If you create sequential nn, I recommend setting `return_sequences=False` and `return_state=False`. This will give you just one tensor, the most basic one, as an output. That should work as a most basic case.